# Stardog Command not found

Tags: macos, path, environment-variables, stardog

I am trying to get to install `stardog` on mac 10.8.5 using the instructions provided at http://docs.stardog.com/quick-start/.

The export path particular directory has been created and for which echo’ed to make sure that environmental variable is set up. The license key that is provided is also in the correct directory. When I try to `run “$ ./stardog-admin server start”` the command is not recognized. So I tried to create an `export PATH to stardog’s bin`, which did not work either.
I have also tried manually adding the path in the following:

```
 - ~/.bash_profile 
 - ~/.profile
```

Still no luck, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Using `zsh` I had a similar problem. For some reason, the docs suggest that from the `stardog-directory-name` directory you can run the command, but it didn't work until you `cd` into the `bin` directory. Once there `./stardog-admin server start` should run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you simply have something incorrect in your `.bash_profile` or `.profile`.  If you run either of the stardog scripts from it's bin directory, it will work.  If you're getting a command not recognized error, that sounds like bash cannot find the `stardog-admin` script.